# Is there a way to download a project from git like torrent downloads?

Tags: git, version-control, unreal-engine4, eof, git-lfs

So i dont have a good internet connection and i'm getting EOF error from git , when i try to download a large file(Game Assets Unreal Engine, uassets). The Project size is more than 78GB's. So i need to find a way to download all the files but in a separate way.

1. I have tried Directory download (it doesn't work as it is a company owned git).
2. I have tried single file download it works but more than 1000++ files needs to be downloaded so it is also not an option.
3. Download as zip only downloads 2GB(Not more than that, sometimes it's less) Also It doesnt download the .git folder , So i can not even recognize it as a repository on Git Desktop.
4. Tried with (Fork , Source tree, VS Code(Git Extension) , VS Studio Community 2019, Git Desktop , Git Bash) those downloads a portion of a file but end's with EOF and all the downloads gets erased when this error occurs.

I am open to suggestions of how do you guys fix this issue. And i can make sure that the EOF error occurs for my Bad internet. So need a way to download this large file in multiple days (like torrent downloads) if it's possible.

Comment: There are a number of settings you can change to extend the timeouts, increase the number of retries etc. And you can let LFS report success even when there are errors so things won't blowup all the time allowing you to retry from the commandline again and again (`set GIT_LFS_SKIP_DOWNLOAD_ERRORS=1`, see https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/git-lfs/git-lfs-config.5.en

Comment: It may also help to do a server to server transfer of the repo from it's source provider (I'm guessing GitHub) which hosts in the US to a local provider, then cloning from the local provider. Azure DevOps has an option to create an instance in your region for example, then use the server to server import feature to create a copy of the repo on your instance.

Comment: i will try your solution and will update you if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to download a project from git like torrent downloads?

No

> I am open to suggestions of how do you guys fix this issue

Nohow. You have choice:

- Change your provider and get more stable and fast connection
- Change your work-style and stop using git in "brainless mode":

  - Git (by design and purpose) not intended to work with big files in repo
  - Store *generated* from repository-stored sources binary artifacts in the repo is always **The Bad Idea (tm)**
  - If you **must** anyway to deal with big files in repo, you have to consider [using Git-LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial) with a) Git-provider, which support git-lfs b) *local* fast LFS-storage

Comment: They are using Git LFS. Also note that Azure DevOps have similar LFS functions that Git Enterprize uses too. That's Why asking. And It is not possible for me to get the Internet that is needed. Thus it is a technical Problem. Also it could also be a Feture in the future of git for those who can not afford good connecting and still able to use it like any other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stale project in very very alpha state hosted at Google intended to achieve what you describe: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gittorrent

but as I said, it appears to be quite stale, no active development and without a healthy number of peers using it, a torrent system is pretty useless.

It's a shame though as I too feel like such a tool would be useful —cloning GCC's source code is an exercise in patience, for example!